# How can I create registration form for users which I can assign role and profile picture?

Tags: forms, user-registration

I am using  Ultimate member's forms for user registration.    I found the way to assign a role to a user but I cant find the way to assing  a profile picture to the user.

The form not only doesnt assing a profile picture to the user, it is no uploading any picture to the site.

I tried everthing said here:
https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/114-photo-uploads-not-working

But still the form doesn't upload pictures or assign a profile picture to the user or upload the image.

Is any alternatives for this? is another plugin capable of assign role and profile picture to users?  Or it is better to try to do a form from zero with php?

Any advice?